# Is there a way to transfer a wordpress project from a windows machine to a Mac?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I want to transfer my wordpress project built in windows to a colleague's Mac, is there in way to achieve this? Is there any wordpress plugin available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Duplicator – WordPress Migration Plugin By Snap](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) or [All-in-One WP Migration By ServMask](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

You can google for the simple it's not like windows or mac migration it's just normal WordPress migration hope you have basic knowledge of how to set working Wordpress environment for Mac

Answer (score 0):

You can use [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) plugin to transfer your site to any platform Or you can take your project database backup for phpmyadmin and zip the Wordpress file and transfer Wordpress file to mac extract them to the project folder from where you want to run the project. Import database base in mac. make changes in `wp-config.php` file if needed.